# Why are the fonts all screwy for remote X11 apps on one Mac client?

Tags: xorg, xforwarding, x11, fonts

I have two Mac OS X clients, both running XQuartz 2.1.6 (xorg-server 1.4.2-apple33). When I SSH into a remote linux system enabling X11 forwarding and launch gnome-terminal, on one Mac the terminal looks correct while on the other, the fonts are all screwy!

`[jnet@Stan ~]$ ssh -X jnet@kyle.local gnome-terminal` produces:
[image: Lookin good!]

`powerbook:~ hp$ ssh -X jnet@kyle.local gnome-terminal` produces:
[image: OH MY GOD, MY EYES!!!!!]

The problem goes away on the powerbook if I zoom in twice:
[image: Looks OK only because the image is scaled down to fit]

**Edit:** This affects a number of apps, not just gnome-terminal. It also affects Thunderbird, for example.

Comment: I would love to tag as `[x11]` `[fonts]`, can anyone help a new user out?

Comment: Seven years later, this seems like a [Wisdom of the Ancients issue](https://xkcd.com/979/). Did you happen to figure it out?

Comment: Sadly @mpontillo I gave up, and now I am using XQuartz.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a font problem - run `Font Book.app`, click **All Fonts**, then select all the fonts in the middle pane (**cmd-a**) and choose **File -> Validate Font** from the menu. This will produce a report of any fonts with issues.

If you find a broken font file, look where it is residing:

- if it's a system font (any path not in /Users), replace it from install media or the working Mac (easier)
- if it's a user font (any path in /Users), delete it - the system fonts should be sufficient, but user fonts take precedence, so if the user installed some borked font it can cause this.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to improve things by doing the following:

On my Ubuntu system, I ran:

```
xrdb -query -all
```

This resulted in the following output:

```
*customization: -color
Xcursor.size:   24
Xcursor.theme:  DMZ-White
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.dpi:    96
Xft.hinting:    1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:   rgb
```

I then took that output and created a `~/.Xresources` file on the Mac, using as its contents the above output of `xrdb -query -all`. Then, on the Mac, I ran:

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

... which I understood should cause the settings to take effect in the current X server. Subsequently, the font rendering seemed better, though it still isn't perfect.

Thanks to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98903/3980) for providing some hints about the a possible fix.

Comment: Nice, glad you found at least a partial fix. I don't have that hardware anymore so I can't test it anymore, but +1 for good relevant info!